# Deep copy of a class with overloading of assignment operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, deep-copy

I am trying to create a deep copy of a class by overloading the equals operator - however, it does not seem to be working. Any help appreciated!

This is the class I am trying to copy:

```
class CMap {

public: 

    int m_nWidth;
    int m_nHeight;
    char* m_pData;
    void setDimensions(int nWidth, int nHeight);
    void operator = (CMap* rhs);

};
```

this is my overloaded operator:

```
CMap& operator = (const CMap&rhs)
    {
        if (this == &rhs)
        return *this;
    memcpy(this -> m_pData, rhs.m_pData, sizeof(char)*rhs.m_nWidth*rhs.m_nHeight);
        return *this;

    }
```

and this is the function call in the main. myMap is an array of CMaps.

```
CMap tempMap;
        tempMap.setDimensions(myMap[0].m_nHeight, myMap[0].m_nWidth);
        tempMap.m_pData = myMap[0].m_pData;
```

Comment: "It does not seem to be working" is non-informative.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson in setDimensions I allocate memory. Unfortunately i have to keep it that way

Comment: @H2CO3by not working, i mean that it is not performing a deep copy.

Comment: So, check for some possible common problems. Can it be that `this->m_pData` is the same pointer as `rhs->m_pData`, for example?

Comment: @H2CO3 i just included it as a check in the overloading operator

Answer (score 4):

- First: that's not the equals operator, that's the assignment operator.
- Second: The assignment operator should have a `const &` parameter, not a pointer, and returns a reference to the object, not anything.
- Third: Except you do something which interferes with the semantics of copying, a assigment overload which does the copy is provided by the compiler automatically.

Respect the point three, you have done one thing which does not do "true" copying: Using a dynamic array through a pointer. The compiler will only copy the pointer, so you have to write your own `operator=` to copy the array by hand (What you are trying in the question).

The easiest solution is: **Use a container like `std::vector` instead of manual memory management**. It has implemented correctly copying and assigment, so yo do not have to write your own `operator=` in your class.

Comment: To #3: he is trying to do exactly that (copying the pointer is not enough, the memory contents that are pointed to should be copied as well.)

Comment: To #3: The compiler really has no choice in the matter. The copy assignment operator is declared *implicitly* if it's not user-declared, and defined when used, so the compiler is just doing what the language says it has to do.

Comment: @Manu343726 manual memory management is the point of my assignment. I take it that i am not overloading the assignment operator correctly then?

Comment: @user1816546 yes. It doesn't have that signature. The signature is `foo& operator=( const foo&)` (Supposing your class is called `foo`). It should return a reference to the object after copying, that is, `return *this;`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I know, thats way I suggest OP to use a standard container, which is easy.

Comment: @Manu343726 oh thank you :) i will try work on it then

Comment: @Manu343726 i tried overloading the operator, but now the program is crashing - any ideas why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43665/discussion-between-manu343726-and-user1816546)